# Why can I only insert a number and not a name?

Tags: python, variables

Hi I'm new to Python and I'm wondering why I was only able to put numbers and not actual names in this code. When I added name I ran into a SyntaxError.

```
my_age = 27
half_my_age = 13
greeting = Hi 
name = Max
greeting_with_name = Hi + Max

print("my_age + half_my_age + greeting + name + greeting_with_name")
```

Comment: What's `Hi` and `Max`?

Comment: you need to put quotes around your string values, e.g. `greeting = "Hi"` otherwise it thinks they are a variable name

Comment: [Python Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp)

Comment: Thank you I can't believe it was such a simple oversight. It worked! @Anentropic

Comment: Have a look at f-strings for your printing at the end https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is a String (Combination of characters) not a number. To Store a string in a variable you need to use double quotes ("") or Single Quotes ('').

In Your Code I think you need to put you HI or name into String like this "HI" or "name" to run you code without any SyntaxError.

I Hope this will help you in your python journey.